# TextView lost after onPause()

Tags: java, android

I'm learning how to add elements to `LayoutParam`.  I add a `TextView` element after each click to ```LayoutParam``.

```
public void send(View v){
        message=edt.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!message.equals("")){
            TextView txt = new TextView(this);
            txt.setText("You: "+message);
            txt.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            txt.setTextSize(20);
            txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            txt.setFreezesText(true);
            llayout.addView(txt);
            scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            edt.setText("");
        }
    }
```

my problem is when i press the Home Button and i open the app again, i don't see any elements. as they have never been.

Comment: obviously you need to store data somewhere ... also consider ListView/RecyclerView for such things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you recalling the send() method in the onResume() method? if not then the data you had will be lost once the activity/fragment resumes. You would need something like this inside onResume():

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    send(new View());
}
```

The parameters inside send, will be whatever view you're passing in.

Comment: i understand from you that i have to call onResume() everytime i call send(). if i am righ. can you tell me how.

Comment: no, you just need one method, called onResume() which is apart of the android lifecycle, and everytime you open your app, onResume() will always be called

Comment: and onResume() is only called, behind the scenes when you hit the home button of the app, and reopen it

Comment: @AymenEva if this has helped solve your problem, don't forget to upvote / accept the answer :)